# Excel averageifs with or function

Tags: excel, average, criteria

I am using the averageifs function, and have one column where I need to calculate the average if either of the criteria are true.

I have tried using the OR function, and tried the curly brackets, but both give me errors.

> =AVERAGEIFS(N1:N612,I1:I612,{"FL","IF"})

There are more ranges, but the coding for those is fine.

To be clear, I want to return an average if column "I" contains (specifically) the letters FL, **OR** the letters IF. Any other letters should mean that entry is not averaged.

TIA!

Answer (score 9):

`AVERAGEIFS` extra criteria is a boolean AND operator, it can't perform OR operations.  But since your columns do not change we can somewhat implement this ourselves:

Here is a simple way using an array formula (entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=AVERAGE(IF((I1:I612="IF")+(I1:I612="FL"),N1:N612))
```

Or if you don't like using array formulas you basically do this manually using `SUMPRODUCT` and `COUNTIF`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I1:I612="IF")*(N1:N612)+(I1:I612="FL")*(N1:N612))/(COUNTIF(I1:I612,"IF")+COUNTIF(I1:I612,"FL"))
```

Answer (score 6):

Chancea has given some good techniques I will list one more that avoids array formulas as many will find it easier to read avoiding the sumproduct.

```
=(SUMIF(I1:I612,"FL",N1:N612)+SUMIF(I1:I612,"IF",N1:N612))/(COUNTIF(I1:I612,"FL")+COUNTIF(I1:I612,"IF"))
```

Comment: Old thread but this answer to date is still the best for readability, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do not think Excel has this feature, but in Google Sheets, I've been using the below to achieve similar results

```
=average(filter($A:$A,($C:$C=$E$6)+($C:$C=$E$7)))
```

giving me an average of the values in `A:A` where `C:C` matches the value in either `E6` or `E7`

unlike an `ifs` / `sumifs` etc., the filter uses `=`, not a comma, thus `$C:$C=$E$6` is used, not `$C:$C,$E$6`

Mathematical symbols are just entered ( so `<>` rather than `"<>"&` )

Comment: If you're using Google Sheets, this seems a lot cleaner than the other solutions and works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this would be to create an additional column (let's call it column J) that returns TRUE if column I contains either "FL" or "IF":

```
J1 = IF(OR(I1="FL",I1="IF"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Then you can reference that column in your AVERAGEIFS formula instead:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(N1:N612,J1:JI612,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your question is:

=AVERAGE(Maxifs(N1:N612,I1:I612,{"FL";"IF"}))