# Averaging values for two criteria in one column

Tags: excel, average

I have a table on information, part of which is shown below, and I'm trying to get the average value of all items in April that have that have the "In Review" and "Withdrawn" designation.

Currently, I'm using the following formula:

=AVERAGEIFS(B:B, A:A, "Apr", C:C, "In Review", C:C, "Withdrawn")

But I get a divide by zero error.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: This is because no values satisfy the conditions (nothing in `C:C` can be both "InReview" and "Withdrawn" at the same time) Check the following thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488364/excel-averageifs-with-or-function

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you meant "In Review" or "Withdrawn". cybernetic.nomad has correctly identified the problem. For a solution, I don't think `AVERAGEIFS` is going to work. `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` will do it, though:

```
=(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"Apr",C:C,"In Review")+SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"Apr",C:C,"Withdrawn"))/(COUNTIFS(A:A,"Apr",C:C,"In Review")+COUNTIFS(A:A,"Apr",C:C,"Withdrawn"))
```