# average specific values in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns in an Excel spreadsheet that look like:

```
Key Values
f   1
f   2
u   3
g   4
g   5
h   6
h   7
j   8
j   9
k   10
k   11
k   12
```

Is it possible to create formula which creates an average that uses values that are associated with a specific key?  For example if I only wanted to include values for f,u,h, and k only (where the average calculated by hand is: 6.5)?

Unfortunately, I can't use VBA in this instance.

Comment: I think this can be easily handled by a pivot table.  So my advice is to look into pivot tables.

Comment: Agreed unfortunately a pivot in this case isn't possible

Comment: Can you not use AVERAGEIF ... https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-averageif-function? You can add another column with a x if you can’t get your criteria to work easily within the averageif statement.

Comment: Agreed with above, AVERAGEIF is the way to go - youll find a nice example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488364/excel-averageifs-with-or-function

Answer (score 1):

Adding all the criteria the provided links show could be quite tedious, here is a way that MAY be simpler. So just as an option:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($B$1:$B$12,$A$1:$A$12,{"f","u","h","k"}))/SUM(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,{"f","u","h","k"}))
```

No need to enter as array formula, which should be an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Brad, just use `AverageIf()` worksheet function:
(In my example I started the first 'f' in cell B2)

```
=AVERAGEIF(B2:B13;"=f";C2:C13)
```

Comment: Or, I think in her case, `AVERAGEIFS()`