# Pandas and Excel results are inconsistent

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using a csv file with a table of all of the different pokemon types, with all different pokemon names in the rows and pieces of information such as their typing, and my goal is to find the average of the pokemon Total(sum of all of their stats) which are of a certain typing. I have attempted that with this coding

```
pokemons = pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv')
print('Bug pokemon average:', pokemons['Total'][(pokemons['Type 1'] == "Bug") | (pokemons['Type 2'] == "Bug")].mean())
```

And I obtain the following result
`Bug pokemon average: 379.52777777777777`
When I was expecting the average to be **365.3611111** which I had worked out in an excel document earlier.
I am wondering if I am doing something blatantly wrong? The csv file is this one https://gist.github.com/armgilles/194bcff35001e7eb53a2a8b441e8b2c6.

Comment: Yes, having the CSV file might help :)

Comment: Default behaviour of pandas mean is to remove null values before compute mean. If you have missing values and you want to take account of them to compute mean, add skipna=False in mean option.

Comment: this looks ok, are you sure the value on excel is right?

Comment: I agree, the code seems OK and the result from the script seems correct. Maybe the problem is in the Excel file.

Comment: I tried using skipna=False and it didn't change a thing
(variables).mean(skipna=False) didn't work.

Comment: For the excel I simply loaded the file in, and used ```=AVERAGEIF(C2:D801,"="&C805,E2:E801)```
(C2:D801 being the range of all the pokemon types (1 and 2))
(E2:E801 being the column with all the pokemon totals in it)
(&C805 just has the word 'Bug' in it)
so I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AVERAGEIF` function in Excel does not consider the range `C2:D801` as an `OR` function. That selection is not filtering the lines that you want. A functioning solution that gives the same results as you expect is `=(SUMIF(C2:C801,"Bug",E1:E801)+SUMIF(D2:D801,"Bug",E1:E801))/(COUNTIF(C2:C801,"Bug")+COUNTIF(D2:D802,"Bug"))`.

Basically you have to compute the sums separately, then average. This gives the expected result of `379.5278`.

I don't think the `AVERAGEIF` function works readily with `OR` conditions. I hope it helps :)

I found this related answer: [Excel averageifs with or function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488364/excel-averageifs-with-or-function)

Comment: TYSM it worked :)